# creating a matrix by a vector in the following condition

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix in **MATLAB** by a vector in the following condition:
The vector is:

```
v=[a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a1; a2; a3; a4; a5]
```

v is a vector of a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 elements that repeats 6 times in this example. 
Now I need to make a matrix based on this vector such that:

```
matrix=
 a1     a2     a3
 a2     a1     a2
 a3     a2     a1
 a4     a3     a2
 a5     a4     a3

 a1     a2     a3
 a2     a1     a2
 a3     a2     a1
 a4     a3     a2
 a5     a4     a3
```

I make a gap between the two blocks of the matrix to show the concept.

The first column of the matrix is a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 (repeating two times).

The second column starts with a2 and decreases to a1, then increase again up to a4. so a2, a1, a2, a3, a4, repeat two times too.

The third column starts with a3...a1...a3 and repeats two times again.

So I need a for loop to make this matrix by the vector elements v.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code (even if it doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather particular sorting, so better define it directly. For example:

```
blockElements=[[1 2 3];[2 1 2];[3 2 1];[4 3 2];[5 4 3]];
matrixElements=[blockElements; blockElements];
```

Then the matrix you want is just:

```
matrix=v(matrixElements);
```

Note that for this to work you don't need v to repeat 6 times a1...a5. It would work also if v is defined like

```
v=[a1; a2; a3; a4; a5];
```

or

```
v=[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't see a straightforward approach for producing that result using a one-liner function; reshaping is a good solution only as long as elements are already placed properly inside the vector... which is not the case, hence the repetition of the values in the vector is kinda useless. On the top of that, I don't see the point of using a for loop to achieve this result when you can use straighe indexing.

```
v = 40:45; % if it's really mandatory you can use repmat(40:45,1,6)
m = [v(repmat(1:5,1,2)).' v(repmat([2 1 2 3 4],1,2)).' v(repmat([3 2 1 2 3],1,2)).'];

m =
    40    41    42
    41    40    41
    42    41    40
    43    42    41
    44    43    42
    40    41    42
    41    40    41
    42    41    40
    43    42    41
    44    43    42
```